# Trying to fit functions that involve numerical integrals and obtaining the error TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object

Tags: python, parameters, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, numerical-integration

with this code I'm trying to make a curvefitting with the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` using a function that contains integrals, fitting then to some data I was given. However, when running the code it is throwing an error that seems to be related with the parameters that I'm trying to fit (the code is below). It gives me the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-13cc86454e5e> in <module>
     88 
     89 vlc_fit = np.vectorize(lc_fit)
---> 90 popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lc_fit,
     91                                       t_data, lc_init_data)
     92 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    782         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    783         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 784         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    785         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    786         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    408     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    409         args = (args,)
--> 410     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    411     m = shape[0]
    412 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    482     if transform is None:
    483         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 484             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    485     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    486         def func_wrapped(params):

<ipython-input-118-13cc86454e5e> in lc_fit(t, args)
     77 def lc_fit(t, args):
     78 
---> 79     p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2 = args
     80     # Main Loop to calculate the Flux
     81 

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

and for what I see, I have no flaws on the code, or at least comparing it to another code given in an other stackoverflow question that fits something that uses integrals in it (here is the link to that code [Fitting data with integral function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331984/fitting-data-with-integral-function))

Here is what I think is the part of my code that is having trouble:

```
import scipy
from scipy.misc import derivative
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit
t_data = np.delete(tce1_time[0:200], np.argwhere(np.isnan(tce1_lc_init[0:200]))[0:], axis=None) #take away the time values where we have a nan value in lc_init
lc_init_data = np.delete(tce1_lc_init[0:200], np.argwhere(np.isnan(tce1_lc_init[0:200]))[0:], axis=None) #take away the nan values in the data array of lc_init

def lc_fit(t, args):
    
    p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2 = args
    # Main Loop to calculate the Flux

    Integral_1 = integrate.quad(integrand_1, 0.0001, 1., args=(t, p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2))[0]
    Integral_2 = integrate.quad(integrand_2, 0.0001, 1., args=(gamma1, gamma2))[0]
    F= 1. - Integral_1/Integral_2
    return F


popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lc_fit,
                                      t_data, lc_init_data)
```

and here is the entire code in case there is something else you want to check

```
import scipy
from scipy.misc import derivative
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit

t_data = np.delete(tce1_time[0:200], np.argwhere(np.isnan(tce1_lc_init[0:200]))[0:], axis=None) #take away the time values where we have a nan value in lc_init
lc_init_data = np.delete(tce1_lc_init[0:200], np.argwhere(np.isnan(tce1_lc_init[0:200]))[0:], axis=None) #take away the nan values in the data array of lc_init



def L(r, P, Z): #it is already multiplied by r² as it is in the derivate into the integral
    '''
    Obstruction function
    '''
    p = P/r
    z0 = Z/r
    z = np.zeros(len(z0)) 
    for i in range(len(z0)):
        # Reflects the information w.r.t. the y axis  
        if z0[i]>0:
            z[i] = z0[i]
        if z0[i]<0:
            z[i] = -z0[i]
        
        if z[i]>1+p:
            return 0.
        elif (abs(1-p)<z[i] and z[i]<=1+p):
            k0 = np.arccos((p**2 + z[i]**2 -1)/(2*p*z[i]))
            k1 = np.arccos((1-p**2 + z[i]**2)/(2*z[i]))
            L0 = k0*p**2
            L2 = np.sqrt((4*z[i]**2- (1+z[i]**2-p**2)**2)/4) 
            return (L0 + k1 - L2)*r**2/np.pi
        elif (z[i]<=1-p):
            return p**2*r**2
        elif z[i]<= p-1: 
            return 1.*r**2


def I_function(r, gamma1, gamma2):
  '''
  Quadratic limb-darkening function
  '''
  mu = np.sqrt(1-r**2) 
  return 1. - gamma1*(1-mu) - gamma2*(1-mu)**2


def integrand_1(r, args1):
    '''
    Integrand in the numerator
    '''
    t, p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2 = args1
    #     p = 0.1 #radius ratio
    #     b = 0.7 #impact. parameter
    #     gamma1 = 0.296 #linear limb darkening 
    #     gamma2 = 0.34 #quadratic limb darkening
    #     a = 2. #normalized semi-major axis (normalized with the star radius)
    #     T = 10. #orbital period
    #     delta = 0. #orbital phase
    omega = 2*np.pi/T #angular velocity
    x = a*np.cos(omega*t+delta)
    z = np.sqrt(x**2 + b**2)
    T1 = derivative(L, r, dx=1e-6, args=(p,z))
    T2 = I_function(r, gamma1, gamma2)
    return T1*T2


def integrand_2(r, args2):
    '''
    Integrand in the denominator
    '''
    gamma1, gamma2 = args2
    return I_function(r, gamma1, gamma2)*2*r


def lc_fit(t, args):
    
    p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2 = args
    # Main Loop to calculate the Flux

    Integral_1 = integrate.quad(integrand_1, 0.0001, 1., args=(t, p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2))[0]
    Integral_2 = integrate.quad(integrand_2, 0.0001, 1., args=(gamma1, gamma2))[0]
    F= 1. - Integral_1/Integral_2
    return F


popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lc_fit,
                                      t_data, lc_init_data)
```

Comment: Well, you should have a look of how `curve_fit()` is working. It figures automatically how many parameters there are to be fitted and `lc_fit` has one, namely `args`. So it is sending one value, which of course you cannot unpack into `p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2` At least that function you have to write as `def lc_fit(t, p, a, b, T, delta, gamma1, gamma2):...`

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, that was really useful, you were right